# Cannot access the hardware

Tags: network-manager, sudo, soundcard, chown

Last night I did a very stupid thing by changing the owner of the directory /usr using the following commands

```
su
password:
chown username:username /usr
```

Now the problem is that I cannot access the network card (i.e. I cannot access the wifi), sound card(i.e. I cannot control the sound and also the sound card is not shown in the sound settings) and also I cannot use the sudo command to gain the super user privileges.
Need help as soon as possible. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to boot to a recovery shell.

If you don't get grub at start up hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while rebooting and you should see this

[image: grub]

Select the recovery mode then open a root shell

[image: root shell]

You may need to remount the file system

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

You can then use **chown** to set it back to its default

```
chown root:root /usr
```

reboot to test

```
shutdown -r now
```